# IP address for Android webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

Now I have been through a tutorial for login/register web service on Android app & I stopped here in an Android Activity once he requested me to put my localhost link via an IP address of my computer, the problem is which IP address I should type in there & how to find it?

AppConfig.java

```
package info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app;

public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.0.101/android_login_api/";

    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.0.101/android_login_api/";
}
```

Comment: well type the file location of URL_LOGIN and URL_REGISTER        ex  if u have the file login.php in your computer , then just type http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_COMPUTER/login.php

Comment: man I mean I dont know what is the IP address of my computer I'm asking how to find it ?

Comment: Open a command promt window and type ipconfig.